# T4 templates for MVC that replicate ASP.net Dynamic Data functionality?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4, asp.net-dynamic-data

I love the functionality that you get with ASP.net Dynamic Data web applications. I love the power and control you get from the MVC framework. Does anyone have T4 templates for MVC that replicate ASP.net Dynamic Data functionality?

Comment: Did you remake Dynamic Data in T4 yet? :) I was more interested in having the nice hierarchy structure to the templates than any specific functionality.

Comment: Benjamin, I ended up writing a custom code generator for MVC. It generates controllers and views. This adds filters for parent keys and add adds links to view child keys. It is a huge time saver and helps with consistency and accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a fan of MvcScaffolding ( http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/ ) with which you can generate everything such as controllers, views, and so on based on data defined on edmx file. Beauty of the package is also that you can customize all the generation of code.

Comment: This gets a +1 since the part about 1 to Many relationships comes close the the Dynamic Data functionality, but still leaves a lot to be done.